# How to go back to a activity that is already open without restarting it and still pass data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a small game that on one screen you can choose an item then go back to the main game activity where you left off and the item will be used. So to know what item the user chose I have to pass data to the main game activity. 
I've done some research and found with code:

```
Item = new Intent(Inventory.this, MainGame.class);//data sent to MainGame activity
Item.putExtra(tools, itemUsed);
Item.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(Item);
```

This opens up the game activity with out restarting it, but it doesn't seem to pass any data to activity. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `startActivityForResult()` is for. In `MainGame`, when you lauch the `Activity` to choose the item, do it like this:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_ITEM = 100;

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseItemActivity.class);
sartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_ITEM);
```

Then, in `MainGame`, override `onActivityResult()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_ITEM:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
                // Get the data from the returned Intent
                Item item = data.getStringExtra("tools"); // or
```

whatever...
                } else {
                    // There was some error choosing the item, or the user
                    //  pressed BACK without choosing anything
                }
        }
    }

in `ChooseItemActivity`, when you want to return to `MainGame` with the chosen item, do this:

```
itemIntent = new Intent(); // Intent to return to MainGame
itemIntent.putExtra("tools", itemUsed); // Add item as extra
setResult(RESULT_OK, itemIntent);
finish();
```